# How to extend scope of ruby mainspace variables within its methods

Tags: ruby, scope

The following code will raise

> in `e`: undefined local variable or method `a` for main:Object (`NameError`)

```
a = '0'
def e
  puts a
end
e
```

How to make `a` accessible within `e`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E.g. make it a global variable:

```
$a = '0'
def e
  puts $a
end
e
#⇒ "0"
```

Comment: Please don’t mark this answer as correct. It is the worst one here.

Answer (score 2):

It's better if you simply use a lambda or instance variable. But assuming you really want to do it this way, you can use `#define_method`:

```
a = '0'
define_method(:e) do
  puts a
end
e
```

Unlike the `def` keyword, `define_method` is not a scope gate, hence it lets you see outer local variables.

Comment: It’s worth to mention that what actually happening is `def` declares new scope, which does not derive binding from the parent’s context. That is the main difference between lambdas and methods and that is why both lambda and block in `define_method` would work: they are closures and hence derive the context.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a parameter for your method, then pass in `a` as the argument when calling it. Parenthesis are optional, though they are important here to show how the parameter is defined and how to pass `a` as an argument.

```
def e(parameter)
  puts parameter
end

a = '0'
p e(a)
#'0'
```